# what is "too starts to"?

Tags: meaning

"The tiny seed hasn’t begun to grow yet.
It will be too late! Hurry!
But finally it too starts to grow into a plant. "

What does "too starts to" mean?

Comment: But finally it starts to grow into a plant too.

Comment: But finally it starts to grow into a plant ***too***. Too means "also".

Comment: But, finally, it, too, starts to grow => remove parentheticals => but it starts to grow

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on ELL (although I confess I wouldn't be surprised if they said it didn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The tiny seed has not yet begun to grow.

This is phrasing that includes both a negation and an exclusionary sense.  "Not yet" is close to the same meaning as "not before this moment".  Both "not" and "yet" modify the verb, despite the distance between them in the original phrasing.

> It will be too late.

It will be excessively late; it will be so late that it won't serve the purpose at hand.

> Hurry!

Be quick.

> But, finally, it [ too / as well / also ] starts to grow.

In contrast, at the end, and the same as others, it does being growing.

Parse "finally, it, too, starts to grow" the same as you would parse "in the end, it (in addition to whatever others are already growing) starts to grow."

In your model, there are no commas surrounding the "too".  In my dialect, such commas are obligatory.  Regardless, "too" usually means "in addition" and often "in addition to (the obvious) others".  That interpretation makes sense in this sentence.

Comment: I think so too.

Answer (score 0):

It means you're suffering from someone's bad writing.

`too` means `also` as Griz and Rath have pointed out.  But, sheesh, that makes me think:

"The tiny seed hasn’t begun to grow yet. It will be **also** late! Hurry! But finally it **also** starts to grow into a plant. "

Ugg. Yes too has two meanings but... ARG now there is another "two" running around.

This is just bad style.  [Too](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20too) can mean "also" but also (ow!) "too much".

Man, that's an annoying way to write.

Comment: Yeah..I am not sure if it's bad writing,but indeed I was confused..Thanks!